# how to create custom elementor widget for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, widget, custom-post-type, elementor

i have custom post type for team member ,now i want to create custom elementor widget for that custom post type so i can use elementor widget to add team members in any page of website.

I have basic knowledge of creating elementor widget , so want to create widget for custom post type

Answer (score 0):

In your page use "post" widget", edit this post, in content menu and query section, you can switch source from "post" to your "cpt" name.
You can create a model with template builder of Elementor, and import with plugin "Ele Custom Skin" for loop all post/cpt.